# Any open source implementations of WS-DM working with JMX?

Tags: java, performance, web-services, distributed, jmx

WS-DM is a web services equivalent of JMX. I am looking for an open source implementation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at [Apache Muse](http://ws.apache.org/muse/)